# how to select with DropDownList.text

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on an Asp.NET project and I am trying to set the selected value of a dropdown list with a text property. For example i have i.e an item in the dropdown list with text `test`. Programmatically can i set it to `selecteditem` by `Text`?. I am using the follwing code but is not working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = "test";
    drpFunction.Text = t; 
}
```

But is not working. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
 string t = "test";
 drpFunction.ClearSelection();
 drpFunction.Items.FindByText(t).Selected = true;
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I had a dropdown that only allowed a single item to be selected. It may be worth mentioning; If an item is currently selected, you have to first deselect the selected option otherwise an exception will be thrown indicating multiple items cannot be selected. 'YourDropDownListId.ClearSelection();'

Comment: FindByText is not valid method

Comment: Is valid from `Net Framework 1.1`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 6):

Setting the itm.Selected = true; only works if you drp.ClearSelection() first.
I prefer the following:

```
drpFunction.SelectedValue = drpFunction.Items.FindByText(t).Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
drpFunction.SelectedValue = drpFunction.Items.FindByText(t).Value;
```

This is better way to select text. By ioden's way it will show an error

> "Multiple Items Cannot be selected in DropDownList"

Answer (score 1):

This [Link](http://www.objectreference.net/post/Select-Text-or-Value-From-DropDownList-Extension-Method.aspx) might help you

```
public static void SelectText(this DropDownList bob, string text)
{
    try
    {
        if (bob.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            bob.Items[bob.SelectedIndex].Selected = false;
        bob.Items.FindByText(text).Selected = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new GenericDropDownListException("value", text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = "test";
    drpFunction.SelectedValue = t;
}
```

The SelectedValue property can be used to select an item in the list control by setting it with the value of the item. However, an exception will be thrown during postback if the the selected value doesn't match the list of values in the dropdown list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should explain your answer instead of just posting a block of code.

Answer (score -1):

Use this...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = "test";
    drpFunction.SelectedItem.Text = t;
}
```

or

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = "test";
    drpFunction.SelectedItem.Value = t;
}
```

this is proper way.......

Answer (score -1):

This works in Web

```
ListItem li=new ListItem(); 

li.Text="Stringxyz";
li.Value="Stringxyz";       // Create object of item first and find its index.

DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(li);
```

This also works fine.