# DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text - html is not marking selected=selected c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, html-select, dropdown

I am binding DropDownList with the data and I am selecting the option based on the value.

Everything is working if I select the DropDownList with Value. that means if I do it selectedValue then it shows the selecting in frontend and it also shows "selected=selected" in HTML. But if I use SelectedItem.Text then it only shows the selection in frontend but HTML doesn't mark slected=selected in the HTML.

I want HTML to mark selected=selected in the HTML so I can use the selected value in my code.

**Please see my code below with selected value and it is working as expected:**

```
DepartmentList.DataTextField = "Title";
DepartmentList.DataValueField = "Id";
DepartmentList.SelectedValue = DepartmentID; 
DepartmentList.DataSource = resultLoc.OrderBy(item => item.Title);
DepartmentList.DataBind();
```

**Please see the screenshot:**

https://snag.gy/VSmz48.jpg

Please see my code below with the selected name and it is not quite working as it is displaying the name in the drop-down as selected but itis not marking selcted=selcted in the HTML.

**Please see my code below with the selected name and it is not working:**

```
DepartmentList.DataTextField = "Title";
DepartmentList.DataValueField = "Id";
DepartmentList.SelectedItem.Text = DepartmentName; // Finance
DepartmentList.DataSource = resultLoc.OrderBy(item => item.Title);
DepartmentList.DataBind();
```

**Please see the screenshot:**

https://snag.gy/hok3FV.jpg

Comment: Instead of `DepartmentList.SelectedItem.Text = DepartmentName;` try `DepartmentList.Items.FindByText(DepartmentName).Selected = true;`

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal if i do that, it doesnt even bind the dropdownlist.

Comment: DepartmentList.SelectedItem.Text = DepartmentName; This is setting the selected item's text to the department name. 
 Definitely not what you want!

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi i want the dropdown shows the department name and also it should mark selected=selected in the html so i can use the value

Comment: @orbnexus See my answer.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi it didnt work. It is throwing a null exception. I guess this is because i am trying to find text before the DataBind.

Comment: You need to call it after DataBind()

Answer (score 1):

As new member and not having much of reputations to comments trying to help by doing some research as mentioned in the comments above in SO and found this answer. Please try this -

```
DepartmentList.Items.FindByText(DepartmentName).Selected = true;
```

[How can you set the selected item in an ASP.NET dropdown via the display text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587341/how-can-you-set-the-selected-item-in-an-asp-net-dropdown-via-the-display-text)

[how to select with DropDownList.text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242010/how-to-select-with-dropdownlist-text)

And the explaination for Text and Value properties here.

[SelectedValue vs SelectedItem.Value of DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564024/selectedvalue-vs-selecteditem-value-of-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
DepartmentList.SelectedValue = DepartmentList.Items.FindByText(DepartmentName).Value;
```

See [this nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17305007/18941) for more detail.